# How to give a mysql record a timeout to expire after 30 minutes?

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x, sql-insert

I was not able to find something relevant anywhere. 
I would like to put a timeout on "password" that I am saving on mysql with python.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO generatedcode(password, codetimeout) VALUES (%s, 
%s)", [passwordd, timestamp])
```

Comment: The only way is to add the timeout value to the record holding the password, and check its value whenever checked.

Comment: @FDavidov can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if request.method == 'GET' or 'POST':
    cur1 = mysql.connection.cursor()
    result = cur1.execute("SELECT password FROM generatedcode "
                          "WHERE DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIME (),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) <= codetimeout;")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not sufficiently acquainted with python and hence I'll leave the specifics of the code to you; I will only present the idea of the solution and the relevant SQL commands (syntax will need to be verified as I don't have an environment to test it).

Let say that you want to set a timeout of 1 hour from the moment you save the password and your table has (at least) the following two fields: `Password` and `Expiration` (I assume that Password would be of binary type to allow encryption and Expiration would be of DATETIME type).

Then, you would implement the following SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO <your table> (Password , Expiration         ) 
      VALUES             (%s       , DATEADD(NOW(),3600))
```

[spaces added just for clarity purposes]

and send that string towards the DB where `%s` would be replaced by the value of the password.

What `DATEADD(NOW(),3600)` does is:

1. Gets the current date and time,
2. Adds one hour to it.

Once you have that inserted into your table, you would later on retrieve the password using the following command:

```
SELECT Password
  FROM <your table>
 WHERE User       = <could be Username or any other key that you are using now>
   AND Expiration > NOW()
```

meaning, get the password (if any) that its expiration datetime is still in the future.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Cheers!!

**EDIT**:

I'm adding hereinafter your code after fixes:

```
@app.route('/signattendance', methods=['GET'])
def signattendance():
    stamp = "signed"
    error = None
    #  now = datetime.datetime.today()
    #  tdelta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=10000)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cur1 = mysql.connection.cursor()
        result = cur1.execute("SELECT password FROM generatedcode WHERE codetimeout > NOW()")

        if result is False:
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO attendance(studentattendance) VALUES(%s,DATEADD(NOW(),3600)", [stamp])
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()
         #  cur1.close()
        flash('Succsefully signed', 'Acepted')
    else:
        flash('You couldnt sign attendance', 'Denied')
else:

return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
return render_template('signattendance.html', error=error)
```

Note that I leave for the DB to check the current time.

Comment: I dont why but it doesnt work, btw when I start typing NOW() it doesnt predict, maybe there is another syntax I should use? And actually I dont encrypt anything right now. Please help ASAP!

Comment: I guess you are using an editor that has _partial_ knowledge of SQL functions and hence it does not suggest. In order to be able to help, you will need to be much more specific: what does not work? What do you get? What is the exact SQL command that you are sending?

Comment: I think your code adds an hour to the record. so basically if I want to insert the password now, DATEADD() will just add another 1hour to it so it is not a timeout.

Comment: Say, you insert the record at 13:45 meaning that the expiration would be registered as 14:45. 59 minutes after, you will be checking if 14:45 > 14:44 which is true of course. If you check again 5 minutes later, you will be checking if 14:45 > 14:49 which is false and hence you would not be retrieving expired passwords. Isn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: I tried but not working :/ . Check the code, I uploaded below!

Comment: sorry but still doesnt work ! It just goes to 'You couldnt sign sttendance'. Btw I why you add DATEADD when inserting? I dont have a timestamp on that table, just id and a string 'Signed'. Password is stored in another table.

Comment: I wonder how are you getting NOW() from DB when the time we are inserting with the password is +1 hour? Does DB has its own DATETIME? I dont understand.

Comment: "_Does DB has its own DATETIME?_": Of course!!! As a general rule (I would strongly recommend you embrace it), whenever you are using a DB for storing and retrieving information, leave to the DB to get current (or future) datetimes. That will make sure that all your users are handled using a centrally managed (and, of course, fully synchronized with itself) CLOCK. Did you try what I posted above? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: thanks for all the help but I figured out a much simplier solution, I will post it so you can take a look at it!